# Circle bounce off circle direction

Tags: trigonometry, circles, physics, angle

I'm making a game in c# where i need a circle to bounce off of another circle, the circle always travels the same speed and there is no gravity so i only need to know the direction at which the circle will travel after it hits the other circle.

The travelling circle is very small and its radius is always the same, the other circles are always larger than the travelling circle but have varying radius'.

I've seen this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81269/angle-of-reflection-off-of-a-circle) but as someone who doesnt know much math I'm wondering if someone can explain it to me a little more basically.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Draw the two circles as they touch, draw a line that joins the two centers, you can imagine the collision boundary as the line through the touch point perpendicular to the line that joins the centers.

Comment: Draw the two circles as they touch, draw a line that joins the two centers, you can imagine the collision boundary as the line through the touch point perpendicular to the line that joins the centers.

Comment: How do i go about calculating the bounce off of a slope like that then?

Comment: Just like if it were straight wall. The parallel component remains the same and the normal changes sign (unless you don't want also a change in direction for the "other" circles)